# MySQL Query full table scan when keys available

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, common-table-expression, full-table-scan

In attempting to pull a large series of columns (~15-20) from several joined tables, I put together 2 views that would pull the necessary information. In my local DB (only ~1k `posts` rows), joining these views worked fine, however; when I created those same views on our production DB (~30k `posts` rows) and attempted to join the view, I realized that that solution wouldn't scale beyond a test dataset.

I attempted to migrate those 2 views (categories data—like `categories.title`—and creators' data—like `users.display_name`) into a CTE `post_data` which, in theory, would act as a keyed version of those views, and allow me to get all post data for the eligible posts.

I have put together a sample [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXHbiVAoAKiyyoNXfTCZxQ/4) with some test data to explain the table structure. The actual data has many more columns, but this is representative of the joins necessary to build the query.

```
table : posts
+-----+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| id  | parent_id | created_by |                 message                  |              attachments               |
+-----+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|  8  | NULL      |          8 | laptop for sale                          | [{"media_id": 1380}]                   |
|  9  | NULL      |          4 | NEW lamp shade up for grabs              | [{"media_id": 1442}, {"link_id": 103}] |
|  10 | 1         |          7 | Oooh I could be interested               |                                        |
|  11 | 1         |          7 | DMing you now! I've been looking for one |                                        |
+-----+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+

table : users
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
| id |   display_name   |        created_at         |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | John Appleseed   | 2018-02-20T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  2 | Massimo Jenkins  | 2018-05-14T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  3 | Johanna Marionna | 2018-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  4 | Jackson Creek    | 2018-11-15T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  5 | Joe Schmoe       | 2019-01-09T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  6 | John Johnson     | 2019-02-14T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  7 | Donna Madison    | 2019-05-14T00:00:00+00:00 |
|  8 | Jenna Kaplan     | 2019-06-23T00:00:00+00:00 |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+

table : categories
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id | created_by |   title    |                      description                      |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |          2 | Technology | Anything tech; Consumer, business or education tools! |
|  2 |          2 | Home Goods | Anything for the home                                 |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+

table : categories_posts
+---------+-------------+
| post_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       8 |           1 |
|       9 |           1 |
|      10 |           1 |
|      11 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+

table : users_categories
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           1 |
|       2 |           1 |
|       3 |           1 |
|       4 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+

table : posts_removed
+---------+----------------------+------------+
| post_id |      removed_at      | removed_by |
+---------+----------------------+------------+
|      10 |  2019-01-22 09:08:14 |          7 |
+---------+----------------------+------------+
```

In the below query, eligible posts are determined in the base `SELECT`; then, the post_data CTE is joined to the result set (limited to 25 rows) and all columns from the CTE are returned.

```sql
WITH post_data AS (
    SELECT posts.id,
           posts.parent_id,
           posts.created_by,
           posts.attachments,
           categories_posts.category_id,
           categories.title,
           categories.created_by AS category_created_by,
           creator.display_name AS creator_display_name,
           creator.created_at AS creator_created_at
           /* ... And a whole bunch of other fields from posts, categories_posts, users */
    FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories_posts
        ON categories_posts.post_id = posts.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories
        ON categories.id = categories_posts.category_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users creator
        ON creator.id = posts.created_by
    /* ... And a whole bunch of other joins to facilitate the selected fields */
)
SELECT post_data.*
FROM posts
        /* Set up the criteria for the posts selected before getting their data from the CTE */
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_removed removed ON removed.post_id = posts.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users user_me ON user_me.id = "1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users_followed ON users_followed.user_id = posts.created_by
        AND users_followed.followed_by = user_me.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories_posts ON categories_posts.post_id = posts.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.category_id = categories_posts.category_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_removed pp_removed ON pp_removed.post_id = posts.parent_id
    /* Join our post_data on the post's ID */
    JOIN post_data ON post_data.id = posts.id
WHERE
(
    (
        users_categories.user_id = user_me.id AND users_categories.left_at IS NULL
    ) OR categories_posts.category_id IS NULL
) AND (
    posts.created_by = user_me.id
    OR users_followed.followed_by = user_me.id
    OR categories_posts.category_id IS NOT NULL
) AND removed.removed_at IS NULL
    AND pp_removed.removed_at IS NULL
    AND (post_data.id = posts.id OR post_data.id = posts.parent_id)
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
LIMIT 25
```

In theory, I thought this would work by selecting the rows based on the base select criteria, then doing an index scan for the CTE based on the Post ID; however, it seems that the query optimizer chooses instead to do a full table scan of the `posts` table.

The `EXPLAIN SELECT` gave me this information:

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |         table          |  type  |         possible_keys         |     key     | key_len |                     ref                     |  rows  | filtered |                       extra                        |
+----+-------------+------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | posts                  | ALL    | PRIMARY,parent_id,created_by  |             |         |                                             |  33870 |      100 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | removed                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | posts.id                                    |      1 |       19 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | user_me                | const  | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | const                                       |      1 |      100 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | categories_posts       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.id                                |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | categories             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | categories_posts.category_id                |      1 |      100 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | users_categories       | eq_ref | user_id_2,user_id,category_id | user_id_2   |      16 | user_me.id,api.categories_posts.category_id |      1 |      100 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | users_followed         | eq_ref | user_id,followed_by           | user_id     |      16 | posts.created_by,api.user_me.id             |      1 |      100 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pp_removed             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.parent_id                         |      1 |       19 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>             | ALL    |                               |             |         |                                             | 493911 |       19 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | posts                  | ALL    |                               |             |         |                                             |  33870 |      100 | Using temporary                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | categories_posts       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.id                                |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | categories             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.categories_posts.category_id            |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | posts_votes            | ref    | post_id                       | post_id     |       8 | api.posts.id                                |      1 |      100 | Using index                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | pp                     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.parent_id                         |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | pp_removed             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.pp.id                                   |      1 |      100 | Using index                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | removed                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.id                                |      1 |      100 | Using index                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | creator                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY     |       8 | api.posts.created_by                        |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | usernames              | ref    | user_id                       | user_id     |       8 | api.creator.id                              |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | verifications          | ALL    |                               |             |         |                                             |      4 |      100 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | categories_identifiers | ref    | category_id                   | category_id |       8 | api.categories.id                           |      1 |      100 |                                                    |
+----+-------------+------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Beyond this, I tried refactoring my query to try and force key usage in the `posts` table, such as using `FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)` in the select, and moving the CTE be the base query and adding a filter `WHERE id IN ({the original base query})`, but it seems the optimizer still does a full table scan.

In case it's helpful to decode what's happening in the query plan:

- At time of writing, there are **33,387** `posts` rows, but the query plan shows
- The query plan shows a full table scan which returns **33,870** rows
- The query plan also shows the derived table (`<derived2>`) as having **493,911** rows

My core questions are:

1. Am I correct when I say that subqueries should only be executed once per result row from the base select query? If so, then the CTE should also use the JOIN on `posts.id` and likely use the table index?
2. Why does the query plan show that it selects **33,870** rows when there are only 33,387? And where do the 493,911 rows come from?
3. How do you prevent a full table scan in this case?

Comment: My core question would have been 'how do I optimize this query?'

Comment: @Strawberry that too! ;)

Comment: One part of your query begins `SELECT post_data.*
FROM posts`, and is then succeeded by a series of LEFT JOINs. Why are you LEFT JOINing tables froom which you select no data?

Comment: @Strawberry I don’t need the qualifying data, only to filter from those tables. If you look at the base `SELECT` query the `WHERE` removes non-qualifying posts. I also tried refactoring this query to get all the data at once AND filter the non-qualifying posts. There is still a full table scan present in that request!

Comment: So, you are turning your left joins into inner joins with your where clause. However, the left joins may make mysql think that a full table scan is more optimal, since you seem to indicate that you want all records from your posts table.

Comment: @Shadow are you saying it would do the full table scan for the CTE since there are no filters in it? Doesn't the `JOIN post_data ON post_data.id = posts.id` filter the CTE on a row-by-row basis? I.e. only an index search should be required

Comment: Since post_data is in effect the posts table left joined by a bunch of other tables and you join this again on the posts table, I'm not sure why the optimiser should think to use an index in this self-join.

Comment: How fast was the query without `JOINing` to the view (`WITH`)?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...  Do the `LIMIT 25` before `JOINing` to the `WITH`:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT ... FROM posts
               JOIN categories_posts ...
        ORDER BY posts.id DESC
        LIMIT 25 ) AS x
    JOIN post_data
       ON post_data.id IN (x.id, x.parent_id)
    ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

Comment: I attempted this solution but it seems that as soon as I join the CTE, the query optimizer does a full table scan. Any thoughts on why it isn't using the merge strategy and is opting for a temptable, even when a `JOIN post_data ON post_data.id = posts.id` (or in your solution, the `JOIN ON post_data.id IN (x.id, x.parent_id)`) is present?